# infinite scroll pattern for single big html data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, infinite-scroll

i know how to detect when user scroll and then we can load next data into div something like below.

```
$( "body").scroll( function() { 
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - ($(window).height()*2)) {
$( "#myDiv").load( "test.html");
}
}
```

my scenario is different. i will show single data html data in page which is itself a big. when i am showing single data from my db then user has to scroll a lot because my single data cover 3-4 pages. so if user need to read whole data then he has to scroll 3-4 pages. so is there any way that i can show partial of a huge html data in a page and when user scroll then i will load again partial data into page and in this way i can load data the way user scroll down. i tried to extract portion of html data and shown in page but page html look bad.so suggest me how to load data with html tags partially for my pages. thanks

Comment: When he scrolls, you can display div after div. You already have the solution. Or am I misunderstanding the question

Comment: 3-4 pages is not that much to make this lazy load for static data. Its maybe have a use if you spend a lot of time to read this data from a database, but from static html is not so big deal to send it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Append the data to your main content div.
Extract the text parts you want to split up, with the right classes etc for css markup. Split them up in seperate files or a php file who serves the needed content.

Then make your original page with headers, footers, sidebars etc.. to make it look pretty. Then give your content div an id like ’mycontent’

Then use ajax to load the next part instead of the div load method you have in your example.

```
 $.ajax("nextpart.php?which=whoweare").done(function (data) {
     $("#mycontent").append(data)
 });
```